# Why do Windows and CPU-Z report different CPU's?

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu

HP, Task Manager, and Device manager say it's a 4417U, but CPU-Z says 5405U.

Comment: CPU-Z reports the same CPU as Windows on 2 machines here. No difference.   I assume you are using CPU-Z V1.99. It may be an anomaly with your particular machine.

Comment: They've got a different socket, but they look otherwise pretty similar to me: [4417U](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=4417U) [5405U](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=5405U). I think you might have to physically look at the chip to be sure--but is it worth it?